# Calculation time for addition of two 8 digits numbers to 4 million digits

Tags: complexity-theory, biginteger

I am hoping to find the calculation time of adding two 8 digits A and B, and keep adding B with sum of A+B, keep adding B, till result is a 4 million digits number.

Comment: In what language/platform? Please give more information.

Comment: Please show how you tried to solve this problem yourself and include an example in your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Reaching a 4 million digit number means reaching/exceeding `M=10^(4*10^6)` which is the first number having 4 million digits. Any 8-digit number is between 10^8 and 10^9-1, so you will have to add B approximately 10^(4*10^6) / 10^8 times in order to reach `M` and because 8 (or 9) is so small compared to 4*10^6, you can ignore it and you get around 10^(4*10^6) additions. And now, if you consider that a standard PC executes around 10^9 instructions per seconds, it will take around 10^(4*10^6-9) seconds which again because 9 is small you get ~10^(4*10^6) seconds.

Note: it is about the complexity here, and not the programming language.

Comment: thanks for you answer, i agree it is a complexity problem. But I am not sure about the PC speed unit instruction/second. the unit i use is FLOPS,and in some gaming GPU, it can reach 1 trillion FLOPS. i mean PC can surely do much better than 10^6 instructions/second, do you think?

Comment: Yes, I have corrected it to the rough value of 10^9 but that does not seem to change the asymptotic result (event if it gets to 10^12 or 10^20).

Comment: well i am still not sure, below there is user casevh's comment on two 100million digits numbers multiplication, it takes about 3 seconds,i mean by addition it shouldn't take so long.          @yi_H: Quick test: raising a million digit number to the 100th power takes about 4 seconds on a fast 64-bit machine. Multiplying two 100 million digits numbers takes about 3 seconds.  – casevh Oct 1 '11 at 20:48

Comment: Well, for multiplying big numbers there are different algorithms and libraries (Fürer's algorithm, Schönhage–Strassen algorithm, Toom–Cook multiplication, Karatsuba algorithm) which have a much lower complexity. But in your case, you have to go explicitly through each step and add B to A, as this is the text of the question (the algorithm). Of course there are many effective possibilities to compute that final result, but with different algorithms.